# How to send form data to email in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I have to send form datas to an email address.
How can I do?
I did some research and I understand that you have to use a library to do this. correct?
What do you suggest?

Comment: Yeah you have to use a library for that, pick one which suits you the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this one might be worth looking into - https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/send-form/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using EmailJS library. I made an account with the free tier (200 free emails/month) added my gmail account, setup a test template and followed the docs https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/ and was able to get something working in less than 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for implementation for **Reactjs** then use like this :

```
// install @emailjs/browser
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const ContactUs = () => {
const form = useRef();

const sendEmail = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
// service_id, templte_id and public key will get from Emailjs website when you create account and add template service and email service 
emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 
'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
  .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
  }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.text);
  });
};

return (
<form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="user_name" />
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="user_email" />
  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea name="message" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that I also achieved this with the very simple https://formsubmit.co solution.

```
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="name" required>
     <input type="email" name="email" required>
     <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```